# Prove that if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, then $\frac{n}{n+2}$ ${\approx_\epsilon}$ 1, for $n$ $\gg$1.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove that if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, then $\frac{n}{n+2}$  ${\approx_\epsilon}$ 1, for $n$ $\gg$1.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: You are asked about $\frac{n}{n+2}$ not $\frac{n}{n+2\epsilon}$. I would suggest using the fact that $\frac{n}{n+2}=1-\frac{2}{n+2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\forall n>1, \,\,\,\,\,1-\frac{2}{n}<\frac{n}{n+2}<1.
$$

Comment: This does not answer the question. The op is required to show that $| \frac n {n+2} - 1| < \varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, not to show that $\frac n {n+2} < 1$.

Comment: It trivially implies that $|\frac{n}{n+2}-1|<\frac{2}{n}$, which goes to $0$.

Comment: I apologize, I have misread your answer. Unfortunately, there is no way for me now to cancel my downvote - unless you edit your post (this seems to be the only approach to cancel votes).

Comment: No worry about the vote, at least we agreed on the point ;)